# Writing csv files to pandas dataframe in aws lambda

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My file format is as below :-

```
[![I am encoding the below file format in cp1252][1]][1] and it works fine




 id "lookupaction"  "relevanceno"   "skipindex" "fname" "lname" "suffix"    "title" "yearjoined"    "email" "phone" "activeind" "created"   "lastchanged"   "changedby"
47028   "A" "5" "0" "Stephen J."    "Salvucci"  ""  "Corporate Counsel" "2008"  "stephen_salvucci@edwards.com"  "949-250-6871"  "0" ""  ""  "44913"
53485   "A" "402"   "0" "Scott" "Rozic" ""  "Assistant General Counsel" ""  "scott.s.rozic@jpmorgan.com"    "212-648-0325"  "1" ""  ""  "47664"
53486   "A" "398"   "0" "Marisol"   "Rubecindo" ""  "Executive Director
50590   "A" "3" "0" "Jonathan"  "Chueng"    ""  "Vice President Counsel
58172   "A" "39"    "0" "Brad"  "Vining"    ""  "Senior Counsel"    ""  ""  ""  "0" ""  ""  "44913"
58173   "A" "40"    "0" "Warren"    "Zeserman"  ""  "Senior Counsel"    ""  ""  ""  "0" ""  ""  "1"
58174   "A" "1" "0" "Joe"   "Jacumin"   ""  "Deputy General Counsel
58175   "A" "1" "0" "Haley" "Peerson"   ""  "Senior Counsel"    ""  ""  "316-200-0338"  "0" ""  ""  "1"
51473   "A" "7" "0" "Kristen Williams"  "Cook"  ""  "Associate General Counsel" "2010"  "kristen.cook@7-eleven.com" ""  "0" ""  ""  "44889"
36558   "A" "2" "0" "Christopher Paul"  "Barr"  ""  "Vice President & Assistant General Counsel"    "2006"  "cbarr@harleysvillegroup.com"   "215-256-5449"  "0" ""  ""  "1"
```

But when i am using this with aws lambda , i decode it using (utf-8) and it give me unicode error.

I am trying to read this csv file and convert it into pandas dataframe.
Below is my code :-

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import sys
import csv


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
#s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

## Bucket to use
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  

   if event:
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        bucketname = str(file_obj['s3']['bucket']['name'])
        filename = str(file_obj['s3']['object']['key'])
        print(filename)
      
        fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=filename)
        body = fileObj['Body']
        data = body.read().decode('utf-8')
         #   data=csv.reader(data.split('\r\n'))
           # print(data)
        

        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
```

I am not able to find right way to create dataframes in aws lambda.
Please help as i am stuck in this for long now.

Comment: I am callign an external API, writing and reading `.csv` files inside lambda and placing them to an s3 buckets, I am importing `from io import StringIO` to do that, maybe that is what you are missing.

Comment: Could you provide the CloudWatch logs?

Comment: @user190549 did you find the answer?

Comment: @Kalenji yes i solved this , will share the solution